# How to use coding for auto-comparing two different fields in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to compare two group fields in attribute table, which are related to the name of villages.

The name of these villages (in both field) are the same but they have in some cases differentiation (because of misspelling).

In order to update my databases I need to find different names and edit them.

They are many names and it doesn't make sense to check them manually.

I think Python or VBA code in ArcGIS is practical.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is using Python or VBA code a requirement for you or just the only way you thought your question could be answered?  Are you talking about doing fuzzy text comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use code to find the mismatched village names so I am going to assume that doing that is not a requirement.  I am also going to assume that you are comparing village name fields from two shapefiles.

First **Join** the two shapefiles based on their village name field (I have used Name and did this from the **Attribute Table**).  Make sure that you choose to **Keep all records**.

[image]

When you hit **OK** you should find that any villages with the same name recorded in both shapefiles have null values in the joined field.  In the graphic below I have clicked on that record to highlight it.

[image]

You can then do a Select By Attributes and use `"name"<>"name_1"` or whatever the two similar name fields are. Then you will have the different ones selected and can just click on the **Show Only Selected** icon and just edit those.

Comment: You can then do a select by attributes and use "name"<>"name_1" or whatever the two similar name fields are. Then you have the different ones selected and can just click on the show only selected icon and just edit those.

Comment: @Mike - I've updated my Answer with your excellent suggestion - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about doing fuzzy text comparisons, check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/682367/386205) on StackOverflow. Particularly, the built-in [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module can do this.

Answer (score 0):

create a test field, type short. 
apply this code in field calculator:

1. choose "python" as a parser:
2. check show block:
3. write these line in pre-logic text-box: 
   `def test(a,b):
   if a==b:
   return 1
   else:
   return 0`
4. at the last text box write this line:
   `test(!field1!,!field2!)`
5. Field1 and field2 should be your two field to be compared:
6. Then you can find the different values on test field, rows with number 1 are same and the rows with 0 are different: